# Using a variable in part of a formula

Tags: excel, vba, variables, formula

I have variables that are determining my range of cells to select, and I want to add a formula at the end that references the variable:

```
Dim first As Integer
Dim Last As Integer


first = (ActiveCell.Row + 1)
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Last = (ActiveCell.Row - 1)
Range("J" & first & ":J" & Last).Select
```

The formula should state something like.

```
ActiveCells.formula(r1c1) = "=RC(first -1)"
```

Comment: what formula do you want to add? i mean the exact formula :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a formula directly like this:

```
Range("J" & first & ":J" & Last).Formula = "=your_formula"
```

This will add your formula in the whole range.
Hope this helps.